# How to change the style of active thumbnail in flexslider

Tags: css, wordpress, flexslider

I want to change the size of thumbnail which is active 'image' in flexslider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class `.flex-active-slide` to style the active thumbnail.

Apply css transform also  - `transform: scale(1.1)`.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

```
#carousel .flex-active-slide img {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```